# How can I have a Visual Studio Report(.rdlc) with account information and also a chart in the same report?

Tags: reporting-services, reporting, rdlc

I'm working on a report in Visual Studio 2008 with their Report tooling and I'm not sure how to approach this conceptually.

I have a report I want to generate. At the top of the report will be a bunch of information about a customer of our site (Name, Address, Phone). Then below will be a chart of the purchases that customer has each month.

My problem is that I want the content at the top of the page to use a query that selects from my Users table in my database. But then I need another query that gets all of the purchases grouped by month.

I've thought one way to approach this would be to place a subreport on the parent report that only contained the chart. The parent report would have the details of the account.

Is this the correct approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have two approach, first use subreport and second use a list and make a group on it. by list you can group your favorite data.